# Sub 15ms key-repeat speed on MacOS Monterey

Tags: keyboard, monterey, bug

MacOS has always had these settings to adjust the keyboard speed.

```
defaults write -g InitialKeyRepeat -int 10 # normal minimum is 15 (225 ms)
defaults write -g KeyRepeat -int 1 # normal minimum is 2 (30 ms)
```

In pre Monterey versions, I was able to go beyond the `15 ms` minimum:

```
defaults write -g KeyRepeat -float 0.4    # 6 ms (15 ms * 0.4 = 6 ms)
```

Monterey has broken this, the key repeat slows down after 10 or 12 characters and stops completely.

Does anyone know how to fix this?